# Copy values from other sheet that is random ordered file

Tags: excel, vba

Hello I'm new to excel and need to get values from other workbooks.

For example, I have `[Book1]Sheet1` like this:

```
      A   B   C   D
      -   -   -   -  
t1 |  2   5   9   4

t2 |  5   8   4   5

t3 |  3   1   2   6
```

I have `[Book2]Sheet1` with columns A B C D among other columns and in random order like this:

```
      E   C    A   F   D   B
      -   -    -   -   -   -
t2 |  4   5   9   4   8    5

t3 |  2   8   4   5   2    1

t1 |  1   1   2   6   1    3
```

I want a vba macro that updates `[Book1]Sheet1` with values from `[Book2]Sheet1` based on the related column and row identifier.

How do I get started?

Comment: If you overwrite all values in Sheet1, all the matrix could be replaced by formulae displaying corresponding cells in other sheet.

Answer (score 0):

To help you get started, try writing a macro to find values in the same workbook.  Here is tutorial that can help:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RR1g9loNhWI